# bash: encode URL to ISO-8859

Tags: perl, bash, url, encoding, character-encoding

I'm currently using this to encode a URL (UTF-8):

```
ENCODED=$(echo -n "válue to éncôde" | \
perl -pe's/([^-_.~A-Za-z0-9])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg');
echo $ENCODED
```

How can I encode into ISO-8859 instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[iso-8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) is not an encoding; it's a whole family of encodings. I'm going to assume you meant [iso-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).]

So you're passing UTF-8 bytes to Perl and you want to convert them to iso-8859-1. [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode) is the go-to module for that.

```
echo -n "válue to éncôde" | \
   perl -MEncode=from_to -MURI::Escape -pe'
      from_to($_, "UTF-8", "iso-8859-1");
      $_ = uri_escape($_);
   '
```

There's also `iconv`

```
echo -n "válue to éncôde" | \
   iconv -f UTF-8 -t iso-8859-1 | \
      perl -MURI::Escape -pe'$_ = uri_escape($_)'
```